# compound predicate in JPA Criteria Query - Use both and, or methods

Tags: jpa, criteria, predicate, criteria-api

Requirement: There are some initial conditions.lets say P1 is the predicate.
There is a date field in database table which could be null. If it is null, I can proceed with initial predicate itself. If it is not null, the value of that field has to be between specified dates.

Approach1:
I am trying to use both 'and' 'or' conditions in my query. The problem is with combination of predicates.

```
Predicate P1 = criteriaBuilder.equal(a,b);
Predicate P2 = criteriaBuilder.isNull(myDate);
Predicate P3 = criteriaBuilder.isNotNull(myDate);
Predicate P4 = criteriaBuilder.between(currentDate,previousDate);


Predicate P34 = criteriaBuilder.and(P3,P4);
Predicate P234 = criteriaBuilder.or(P2,P34);
Predicate P1234 = criteriaBuilder.and(P1,P234);
criteriaBuilder.where(P1234);
```

Expected conditions in query: P1 AND (P2 OR (P3 AND P4))

Actual conditions in query: P1 AND P2 OR P3 AND P4

Approach2: Use some mathematics set theory and expand the brackets.

```
Predicate P12 = criteriaBuilder.and(P1,P2);
Predicate P34 = criteriaBuilder.and(P3,P4);
Predicate P134 = criteriaBuilder.and(P1,P34);
Predicate P12134 = criteriaBuilder.or(P12,P134);
criteriaBuilder.where(P12134);
```

Expected conditions in query: (P1 AND P2) OR (P1 AND P3 AND P4)

Actual conditions in query:  P1 AND P2 OR P1 AND P3 AND P4

In both the approaches I am missing the brackets. Suggest me the approach to get these brackets. Is there a better approach to satisfy the requirement ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In both cases, the expected conditions and the actual conditions are equivalent. Expressions are evaluated from left to right, and `AND` takes precedence over `OR`.

Looking at your first query, both with and without brackets, the following combinations yield true, while all others will yield false:

```
SELECT true AND true OR true AND true;
SELECT true AND false OR true AND true;
SELECT true AND true OR false AND false;

SELECT true AND (true OR (true AND true));
SELECT true AND (false OR (true AND true));
SELECT true AND (true OR (false AND false));
```

Comment: For sure they are not the same. Check this query:
`SELECT
 '1',
 FALSE AND (TRUE OR (TRUE AND TRUE))
UNION ALL
SELECT
 '2',
 FALSE AND TRUE OR TRUE AND TRUE`